# Can't install PM2 services via Ansible on an Ubuntu EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, node.js, ansible

I'm using Ansible to create a pm2 service on a EC2 / Ubuntu instance.  Below is the script.  When I run it, PM2 is installed and the service is enabled.  When I run pm2 list, I don't the see the service, but I can grep it (ps aux | grep node) and see that it's running.  It also seems like a shadow copy of pm2 is running and loading the app, but I can't seem to control it.

```
- hosts: comm
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
    - npm: name=pm2 global=yes
    - name: configure pm2 to restart on startup
      shell: pm2 startup ubuntu >& /dev/null chdir=~/ executable=/bin/bash
      sudo: yes
      sudo_user: root
    - command: sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin pm2 startup ubuntu -u ubuntu
      sudo: yes
    - command: /usr/bin/pm2 save
    - command: /usr/bin/pm2 start /home/ubuntu/something/app.js --name something
```

Answer (score 1):

This playbook is not idempotent, the `shell` task is going to run every time the playbook is run, you need to supply a [`creates`](http://docs.ansible.com/shell_module.htm) argument to that task.

In the [current version](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/3adc5d5ad80c3c4a5367fb5bde6ca3fea6b8fd12/lib/CLI.js) of PM2:

```
var scriptFile = '/etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh',
  script = cst.UBUNTU_STARTUP_SCRIPT;
```

Also, the use of `sudo` is redundant, as it is already specified globally above, and the default is to `sudo` to `root`, so that's redundant as well.

Additionally, once there's an `init` script for the service, it would be better to use the [`service`](http://docs.ansible.com/service_module.html) module to manage it.

Comment: Even after running the startup command, getting the init script, and restarting, I don't see pm2 in the list of services running on the box (from `service --status-all`).  Would be nice to use the service module for sure, can you expand your answer in that area?